# How to change the date format of a parameter in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, date-format

By default Crystal Reports will display dates as 6/1/2011(month/day/year), so I have to change the formatting to 01-06-2011(day/month/year) by using the formula:
`ToText({MyDate}, "dd-MM-yyyy")`.

My question is how do I change the date format when using date parameters?

For example:
This is my date parameter :{?date}
This is my formula (called {@displaydate}) to display the chosen date on the report:
`"From : " & Minimum({?date}) & " To :" & Maximum({?date})`

In design view:
DATE    :   {@displaydate} {?date}
In Preview Mode:
DATE : From : 6/1/2011 To : 31/6/2011

Answer (score 3):

```
"From : " & ToText(Minimum({?date}), "dd-MM-yyyy") & 
" To :" & ToText(Maximum({?date}), "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am Create Formula In The Crystel Report It Converts the Value of datetime format to date.
I use following formula.

```
CDate ({TRAN_STUDENT_INFO.Adm_Date})
```